# How to insert data to a sql server relational database that involve primary and foreign keys in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a problem and really need your help.
I have two inter-related tables which are:
Persons(id(pk),first_name,last_name,age,address,gender_id(fk)).
Genders(id(pk),gender_type).
So by looking at these tables, you can see that the Genders table has a reference on the Persons table which is gender_id column.
In my C# code, I have a gender combo box that fetches data from the Gender table(ie male and female).
So what I want is when the user selects male, the male id should be save under the gender_id column in the Persons table like wise female.
Any feedback will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the problem. The relation is actually the other way around (I hope...): The Persons table has a reference to the Genders table. So the code which retrieves the data for your combobox should also retrieve the associated GenderID. If a user selects `Male`, you know the associated id, and use that in your `insert`. Since that id exists in the Genders table (you got it from there) the foreign key is not a problem.

Comment: Why not use a `datatable` for your genders? Set the text value to the combobox's DisplayMeber and the ValueMember as the ID. Then the user will see "Male" and "Female", but when you complete your SQL use the ValueMember.

Comment: what's the binding code you have...nothing you have said is wrong so far

Comment: Unless you trying to accommodate all the various gender identification possibilities a table for Gender is a bit overkill. You could just have the Gender column be a char(1) with a constraint to be in ('M', 'F')

Answer (score 0):

You Have a dropdownlist which is filled from the genders table. drop down has a text which is set to gender_type and a value which is set to id of genders table.
when the user selects a item in dropdownlist get the value of selected item and store in the Persons table

Comment: That's a good idea. I will try and and get back to you. Thank you